# High Memory Utilization in Juniper ACX2100

Tags: router, juniper, memory

Recently i observed that one of our juniper AC2100 has only free 3% of memory.But i'm unable to understand which thing is causing such high memory usage or what i can do free the memory so it won't cause any problem in future. Any help appreciated.

Below is the output of show system memory command on juniper device

```
System memory usage distribution:
       Total memory: 1548288 Kbytes (100%)
    Reserved memory:   27680 Kbytes (  1%)
       Wired memory:  204776 Kbytes ( 13%)
      Active memory:  302756 Kbytes ( 19%)
    Inactive memory:  712516 Kbytes ( 46%)
       Cache memory:  246780 Kbytes ( 15%)
        Free memory:   53040 Kbytes (  3%)
```

Comment: I'm not saying there isn't a problem here, but on any device free memory is wasted memory, so typically it's used as cache or for any other non-critical application, allowing the operating system to reassign it if needed otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On an ACX1100, that command is exactly what you need (18.2) - if you let it page down, it will show you every process and exactly how much memory they are consuming eg:

```
System memory usage distribution:
       Total memory:  756736 Kbytes (100%)
    Reserved memory:   13856 Kbytes (  1%)
       Wired memory:  101416 Kbytes ( 13%)
      Active memory:  421208 Kbytes ( 55%)
    Inactive memory:   57360 Kbytes (  7%)
       Cache memory:  159632 Kbytes ( 21%)
        Free memory:    2712 Kbytes (  0%)
Memory disk resident memory:   37640 Kbytes
VM-Kbytes(  %  ) Resident(  %  ) Map-name
  1048576(99.99)   459876(43.86) kernel map
   247624(23.62)    49552(20.01) kmem map
     1216(00.12)     1216(99.99) exec map
    12380(01.18)     1032(08.34) pipe map
    86304(08.23)    85600(99.18) buffer map
    32768(03.13)    32768(99.99) pager map
Pid     VM-Kbytes(  %  ) Resident(  %  ) Process-name
...
   2524     28436(01.10)    14100(01.81) /usr/sbin/eventd -N -r -s -A
   2675         0(00.00)        0(00.00) [crypto]
   2676         0(00.00)        0(00.00) [crypto returns]
   2781      2316(00.09)      656(00.08) /usr/sbin/cron
   3120      2320(00.09)      864(00.11) /sbin/watchdog -t-1
   3122      2744(00.11)     1300(00.17) /usr/libexec/bslockd -mp -N
   3124      4720(00.18)     2020(00.26) /usr/sbin/tnetd -N -l
   3128     97320(03.75)    32740(04.21) /usr/sbin/chassisd -N
   3129     23604(00.91)    12352(01.59) /usr/sbin/sdk-vmmd -N
   3132     21476(00.83)    11220(01.44) /usr/sbin/craftd -N
   3136     62192(02.39)    26692(03.43) /usr/sbin/mgd -N
   3138     54096(02.08)    32888(04.23) /usr/sbin/mib2d -N
   3139      6896(00.27)     2400(00.31) /usr/sbin/inetd -N -w
   3147     24728(00.95)    14028(01.80) /usr/sbin/ppmd -N
   3148      2396(00.09)     1144(00.15) /usr/sbin/smartd -n
   3154     22024(00.85)    12096(01.55) /usr/sbin/bfdd -N
   3155     27184(01.05)    14548(01.87) /usr/sbin/clksyncd -N
   3157     22588(00.87)    12604(01.62) /usr/sbin/lfmd -N
   3158     25836(00.99)     8856(01.14) /usr/sbin/smid -N
   ...
   3820    389988(15.02)    52348(06.73) /usr/sbin/rpd -N
   3821     52368(02.02)    29272(03.76) /usr/sbin/l2ald -N
   3822     21648(00.83)    12124(01.56) /usr/sbin/apsd -N
```

Try it with `| match rpd`.  ACXs aren't designed to handle a huge amount of L3 routes and will max out somewhere around 12,000.